# Set the height of a div inside an SVG foreignObject to 100%

Tags: html, css, svg

I have the current svg structure:

```
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; top: -0.875px;" viewBox="0 0 191 220.54780283043706" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin">
    <desc style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);">Created with Raphaël 2.1.2</desc>
    <defs style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"></defs>
    <path fill="#000000" stroke="#585247" d="M95.5,2L189.26794919243113,56.13695070760927L189.26794919243113,164.4108521228278L95.5,218.54780283043706L1.7320508075688679,164.4108521228278L1.7320508075688679,56.13695070760927Z" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="1%"></path>
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
        <div>
            <p>Hullo</p>
        </div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

I want to set the height of the div inside of the foreign object to 100%, but it doesn't work.

I have tried setting the height of everything inside including the `foreignObject` itself to 100%, but have been unsuccessful. Is there anyway to specify a percentage based height in a foreign object svg?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zhh1nsxc/1/

Comment: The div seems like it's 100% height to me. Why do you think it's not?

Comment: @RobertLongson well it would be centered if it had 100% height, but it isn't.

Comment: Set background-color: red; on the div and you'll see it's 100%. The `<p>` within it however is a problem...

Comment: @RobertLongson It seems like the fiddle is a bit different than my working environment...I'll have to try out some more things and come back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real structure of the code was:

```
<section> // this needed 100% height
    <section>
        <figure>
            <svg> // finally here
```

And it turned out all the way up at the top the element there had to be 100% height.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;

   p {
      display: table-cell;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
   }

}
```

to this:

```
div {
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}
p {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zhh1nsxc/2/)

Comment: Whoops I still had it in SASS syntax on the fiddle...I think you might have still helped me find the problem however.